# How to delete elements of the same index in 2 different list?

Tags: python

I have 2 different list. 
 First list is `username = ["kirito", "asuna"]`, second list is `password = ["kirigaya","yuuki"]`
 I want the user to input a number corresponding the index of each list and delete it.
Example

```
for (i, item) in enumerate(username, start=0):
   print(i, item)
#this is how I print the list of elements with their indexes given as a guide for the user
delete = input("[ What account do you wish to delete? ]\n")
for x in range(len(username)):
   if delete == username[x]:
      del username[x]
      print("[ Deleted: ]")
      print(delete)
```

This deletes the element which is given as input by the user and not its index 
 So only the specified element by the user of the first list gets deleted.. 
**What I want is to specify the index instead of the elements itself so I could delete the specified index of both list ?**

Answer (score 1):

Use method `list.index`:

```
>>> username = ["kirito", "asuna"]
>>> password = ["kirigaya","yuuki"]
>>> name_to_delete = 'asuna'
>>> username.index(name_to_delete)
1
>>> idx = username.index(name_to_delete)
>>> del username[idx]
>>> del password[idx]
>>> username
['kirito']
>>> password
['kirigaya']
```

If the value to be deleted does not exist, it will raise ValueError, so you may also need to use the try statement:

```
>>> username.index('hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 'hello' is not in list
```

However, in practice, I will not complete these tasks in this way. It would be better to use a dictionary to replace two lists:

```
>>> users = {"kirito": "kirigaya", "asuna": "yuuki"}
>>> del users[name_to_delete]
>>> users
{'kirito': 'kirigaya'}
```

Comment: Completely agree with @mechanic-pig, **dictionary** option is the cleaner approach for that kind of pairs.

Comment: is it possible to make an empty dictionary to be filled by user later?

Comment: Yes you can initate empty dict and then assign to them like:
`credentials = {}`
`credentials['johndoe'] = '123'`
`credentials['sansmith'] = '456'`
`print(credentials)`
`#{'johndoe': '123', 'sansmith': '456'}`

Comment: Dictionaries are mutable objects, which means you can dynamically add and remove elements.@KLD

Comment: Ok this helps a lot..